# Enrichments vs Internal homs

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, braided-tensor-categories, enriched-category-theory, yoneda-lemma

Consider the definition of existence internal homs for a general monoidal category category $\cal{C}$, mainly the existence of an adjoint for the functor
$$
X \otimes -: \cal{C}  \to \cal{C},
$$ 
for each object $X$ in $\cal{C}$.

Denoting this functor by 
$$
hom_X(-):\cal{C} \to \cal{C}
$$
it is tempting to ask if the functor 
$$
hom: {\cal C} \times {\cal C} \to {\cal C}, ~~~~~~~ (X,Y) \mapsto hom_X(Y),
$$
gives an enrichment of $\cal{C}$ over itself. Is this correct?
Moreover, is the existence of an enrichment of $\cal{C}$ over itself equivalent to the existence of internal homs?

More generally, when people speak of  **internal homs** for a category, not necessary monoidal, are they just talking about an enrichment of the category over itself? Is this what usually understood by "a category with internal homs"?

Comment: Yes, a closed monoidal category is enriched over itself.  In the symmetric case this is section 1.6 of the standard reference *Basic concepts of enriched category theory* http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html.  I think that usually when people say "internal homs" they are referring to a monoidal structure being closed, or more generally to a closed category structure (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+category) -- it doesn't make sense to talk about enrichment over a category until it has a monoidal/closed/multi/etc structure.

Comment: I would expect that a monoidal category $C$ could happen to be the underlying category of some $C$-enriched category in a "wrong" way so that the enriched hom-objects aren't right adjoints of the tensor product, but I don't have an example ready to hand.

Comment: Here's an example of "wrong-way" self-enrichment: the category $Cat$ of small categories is enriched in itself in the _usual_ way since it is cartesian closed. But it also has _another_ self-enrichment where you take the maximal subgroupoid of each hom-category. This sort of variant enrichment is important e.g. to make $Cat$ into a simplicial model category.

Comment: @Tim: Put this as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mike says, it is indeed the case that a closed monoidal structure gives rise to a self-enrichment of a category. This is an often-used fact.

Here's an example of "wrong-way" self-enrichment: the category $\mathsf{Cat}$ of small categories is enriched in itself in the usual way since it is cartesian closed. But it also has another self-enrichment where you take the maximal subgroupoid of each hom-category. This sort of variant enrichment is important e.g. to make $\mathsf{Cat}$ into a simplicial model category.

For that matter, $\mathsf{Cat}$ also has a self-enrichment where you take the usual $\mathsf{Set}$-enrichment, and regard the hom-sets as discrete categories.

Answer (score 3):

I see that this question has an already accepted answer but I think that may be of interest.

There is a notion of category with internal hom with no reference to a monoidal structure, that is the notion of a [closed category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+category).

This is a category with an internal-hom functor and few other natural and extranatural transformations satisfying coherence conditions.

The best reference on the subject is Eilenberg and Kelly's *Closed categories*. In this paper the authors show how you can enrich in any closed category, without any monoidal structure, and personally I think is one of the best references for enriched categories (even if it is not the most complete).

I would strongly suggest to take a look to the article, personally I have learned and understood more enriched-category theory from that paper than other reference.

I hope this may help.