# Self-enrichments of rigid monoidal categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

A right closed monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ is one for which the functor $X \otimes -$ admits a right adjoint, for every $X \in \mathcal{C}$. As explained here

[Enrichments vs Internal homs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303265/enrichments-vs-internal-homs)

this gives an enrichement of $\mathcal{C}$ over itself. In this question

[Rigid monoidal and closed monoidal categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368206/rigid-monoidal-and-closed-monoidal-categories)

it says that rigid monoidal categories are closed monoidal. So what does the self-enrichment of a rigid monoidal category look like?

Comment: $Hom(X,Y)=X^{*}\otimes Y$. BTW you need symmetry in the first line, or that would just be right closed.

Comment: @Fernando: I have added right thanks!

Comment: @Fernando: How does one relate the set $Hom(X,Y)$ with $V^* \otimes Y$?

Comment: @TimCromby There's a notational ambiguity. I'll write $Hom(X,Y)$ for the set of morphisms and $[X,Y]$ for the internal hom. As Fernando says, one _defines_ $[X,Y] = X^\ast \otimes Y$. The idea to keep in mind is that if you already had the closed monoidal structure, then you would have defined $X^\ast = [X,I]$. You would have a map $X^\ast \otimes Y = [X,I] \otimes [I,Y] \to [X,Y]$ internalizing the composition operation $Hom(X,I) \times Hom(I,Y)\to Hom(X,Y)$, and using rigidity you'd have shown this map to be an isomorphism. When setting up the closed structure, you run that picture backwards